# How to run a node.js project on the site?

Tags: node.js, web

There is a website, installed node js, uploaded the project there, launched the project through the console, everything is fine in the console. Site is empty

Comment: Have you started node process with pm2 or any other? Is there everything ok?

Comment: Please provide proper and complete details. Where is the website located? What is the project structure like? How is the website hosted? You can't run the project locally and then expect the public to be able to access it. You need a proper node.js hosting provider.

Comment: The project works locally. A little work authentication-authorization + recaptcha.

Comment: The site now displays an empty index.html file

Comment: Clarify your problem. Its impossible to answer your question like this.